# Cannot access user properties (passed as res.locals.user) using express and hbs view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I use this code to check if user token is correct, and put user into req.locals

```
exports.isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.cookies.jwt) {
        try {
            const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(
                req.cookies.jwt,
                process.env.JWT_SECRET
            );

            const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
            if (!currentUser) {
                return next();
            }

            if (currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
                return next();
            }

            res.locals.user = currentUser;
            return next();
        } catch (err) {
            return next();
        }
    }
    next();
};
```

After that, I render the view. This is my header, name of the user should be displayed here, but it seems to be empty. There is a user, and it is not empty, but for some reason i cannot access directly his name using hbs

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand p-0 bg-dark">
<div class="container">
    {{#if user}}
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-none d-md-flex mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link logout" href="/users/logout" data-abc="true">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex align-items-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EYFtR83.jpg" class="rounded-circle"
                                                      width="30"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" data-abc="true">
                <span>{{user.name}}</span>
                <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down'></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    {{else}}
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-none d-md-flex mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/users/login" data-abc="true">Log In</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/users/signup" data-abc="true">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Any ideas?

UPD
Added hbs configuration and controller function that renders page

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + "/views/partials");

app.engine("hbs", engine ({
        layoutsDir: "views/layouts",
        defaultLayout: "layout",
        extname: "hbs"
    }
));
```

Also, here is controller method, that renders page

```
exports.getHomePage = async (req, res, next) => {
res.render('home');
};
```

Comment: Why should it be available in your HBS? You haven't shown any code where you run the HBS, let alone pass data from `locals` into it.

Comment: Updated, here is hbs configuration and render method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views in Express don't have access to the request object. They only have access to the data in the object passed as the `locals` parameter:

```
const locals = { put: "some data here" };
res.render('home', locals);
```

You aren't passing any data at all.